# Grid not updating on edit button press

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a gridview.

I am trying to edit it, but value is not getting updated.

**My Code:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.51.71;Initial Catalog=WebBasedNewSoft;User ID=sa;password=prabhu");

            BindGrid();
        }
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from emp", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = GridView1.EditIndex;

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

            string eName = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text.ToString().Trim();

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update emp set empName='" + eName + "'", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                BindGrid();
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            finally
            {

            }

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
```

Please let me know the point where i am making mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this...becuase...when you click on edit button your pageload event is called first....and on pageload you bind the gridview again...so its edit index is lost because it binded again...and it set edit index to -1 each and everytime...

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
              {
             con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.51.71;Initial            Catalog=WebBasedNewSoft;User ID=sa;password=prabhu");

            BindGrid();
        }
}
```

**Edit1**: OP After Update Edit Mode Doesnt goes..
You Have to Set gridview Edit index before Its binding like below....

```
try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update emp set empName='" + eName + "'", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;//Put this line Before the Binding of GridView
                BindGrid();

            }
```

Comment: Thanx i tried it, but with this text boxes which i edit does not go[Values changes/updates thats my work is done]. But text boxes are not gone, they remains as it is on the page

Comment: @M.N.S. can not understand u?

Comment: when we click on any row's edit button, textboxes appears for each field so that we can edit them. When i edits the value in textbox and press the update button, Values in the database got changed[Due to update query] but that textboxes for edit are not getting removed from grid. They remains as it is

Comment: @M.N.S. its ok u can take time ...and can wait too more better answer too if u like...

Comment: nope dude, only 1 minute is remaining. My work is done by this answer

Answer (score 3):

use `BindGrid()` inside `Page.IsPostBack` as follows on `Page_Load` event

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     BindGrid();
}
```

### Edit 1

I think the following line should work

```
   BindGrid();
   GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
```

As it is not working see is there any error in the catch block.

```
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
       Response.Write(ex.Message);
  }
```

See weather there is some error or not?

Comment: thanx i tried it, but with this text boxes which i edit does not go[Values changes thats my work is done]. But text boxes are not gone, they remains as it is on the page

Comment: nope after putting GridView1.EditIndex = -1; before BindGrid(); it worked